# Determine some values of a given piecewise-linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am unsure how to begin. The question is

$f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is defined as follows: $f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x - 4, & x > 0 \\ -3x + 1, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Determine $f(0), f(-1), f(1), f(\frac 5 2)$.

I am unsure how to do this, it would be very helpful if someone could give me a step by step guide.

Comment: Check which numbers are greater than zero and less than or equal to zero and apply the corresponding formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x-4,&x\gt0\\
-3x+1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases},$$ means that $f(x)=2x-4$ when $x$ satisfies the condition “$x\gt0$”, and $f(x)=-3x+1$ when $x$ doesn't satisfy the condition “$x\gt0$”, i.e. when $x\leqslant0$. So to determine the value of $f$ for a certain $x$ we would first have to know whether this number satisfies the first condition or the second. Let's take as an example $x=4$: We know that $4\gt0$, hence we would opt for $f(x)=2x-4$, since that's how the function is defined for numbers that are $\gt0$. Hence $f(4)=2\cdot 4-4=4$. Can you determine the values of $f$ for the other numbers?

Comment: @user335174 You're welcome, glad this helped! :-)